# Appending an unknown amount of WHERE parameters

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to find the most logical (as always) way to accept a list of WHERE parameters in a query. I am running into the common issue of how to determine if it's the end of an array and I need to add or not add another "AND"

```
$params = array(
   array("id","=","1"),
   array("id","!=","2"),
   array("name","=","test"),
)

someQuery($params);

private function someQuery($where = null){
    $this->q = "SELECT stuff FROM table";
    if ($where){
        $this->q .= " WHERE ";
        foreach($where as $x){
           $this->q .= implode(" ", $x);
           if (!notLastElement) $this->q .= " AND ";
        }
    }
}
```

I've seem suggestions of end(), reset(), slice, for loops with counters, etc. But no one seems to agree on one answer. I believe end() will not work in my loop. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Gather as an array and [`implode()`](http://php.net/function.implode).

Comment: You could also use `WHERE 1=1` and add the rest.

Comment: @tdoakiiii If Jay's answer below solved it, consider accepting the answer to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as easy as imploding the parameters array, for example -

```
private function someQuery($where = null){
    $this->q = "SELECT stuff FROM table";
    if ($where){
        $parameters = array();
        foreach($where as $x){
            $condition = implode(' ', $x); // I'd review this - why are you forming your parameter array the way that you are?
            array_push($parameters, $condition);
        }
        $conditions = implode(' AND ', $parameters);
        $this->q .= ' WHERE ' . $conditions; // only concatenate once
    }
}
```